# Is this a right way to make php template?

Tags: php, templates, include

Here is my code

```
    <?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
<?php
include_once "mysql_connect.php";
mysql_query("UPDATE viewcounter SET `views` = `views`+1 WHERE id='1'");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM viewcounter WHERE id='1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id = $row["id"];
$pagename = $row["pagename"];   
$views = $row["views"]; 
};
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Like Dislike</title>
<meta name="Description" content="Like Dislike  " />
<meta name="Keywords" content=" likedislike,tk,thumbs up,thumbs down,like,dislik,love,hate,tk" />

</head>

<body>
<center>
<h1>Like/Dislike</h1>
<a href="what-should-be-here" onMouseOver="image1.src=loadImage1.src;" onMouseOut="image1.src=staticImage1.src;">
<img name="image1" src="http://www.likedislike.tk/images/left-blue.png" border=0></a>
<img src="images/logo.gif" alt="desert" width="126" height="168" align="middle" /><a href="http://www.likedislike.tk/2-justin-bieber" onMouseOver="image2.src=loadImage2.src;" onMouseOut="image2.src=staticImage2.src;">
<img name="image2" src="http://www.likedislike.tk/images/right-blue.png" border=0></a>
<br />
<?php echo ThumbsUp::item('1')->template('thumbs_up_down') ?>
<?php echo ThumbsUp::item('1')->template('mini_poll') ?>
<?php print $views; ?> views
</center>
</body>
</html>
<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Now i am confused..

where should i put this `<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>`
should i put inside body or outside.
and i want to add more java script so should i load them in header.php or in the page ?

What is the best way to speed up everything and load those java script fast?
Can i load all the java script,css and some php script in header.php?
Thanks i am only 14 so don't tell me i am stupid :)

I try it and it works but i just wanted to know its right way or not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your code `<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>` has different purpose than you assumed. It seems it is designed to deal with HTTP request headers and should be invoked before any output is sent to the browser.

You should be aware that **not even a space should be sent (displayed) before `header.php` is executed** (assuming it contains `header()` PHP function calls) - please see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Secondly, if you want to include JavaScript, you should do it in HTML `head` section or later, in the body. The way you should solve it varies depending on what you want to achieve. The best way is to **combine as much JavaScript as possible in one file and compress it**, do **similar thing with CSS** (combine all files and compress them).

By combining and compressing JS and CSS files you are making less requests to the server and less requests will be blocked (browsers have limits for concurrent requests to same domain).

Here is some documentation on including JavaScript in HTML documents: [www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html).

Comment: Here is the site likedislike.tk

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript includes and additional CSS files are part of the HTML markup, and should probably be in the `<head>` area.

You'll typically list your PHP includes at the top of a file. The PHP is executed by the web server, and only outputs text if you use `echo`, `print`, etc. You might pick apart some WordPress themes or PHP tutorials and look at how (and pay close attention to why) people structure their markup and PHP the way they do. There's usually no right or wrong way to do things, but there are best practices to follow and the best overall layout/plan depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to load in header is only that you need for loading page correctly. Because each 
script tag will lock your page loading until this one loads. So if you have big javascripts your users will see blank page long time(minutes, maybe hours :)))).